# Maintain different Dropbox locations for one Dropbox account on different hosts

Tags: linux, dropbox

We've got a user who is asking if it's possible to keep two config.db's, and use one or the other based on the host name, for *the same* Dropbox account (not two Dropbox accounts).

For example:

```
~/.dropbox/box123/config.db
~/.dropbox/box456/config.db
```

The primary goal is so that the location of the Dropbox folder can be different on different hosts.  For example, on box123, Dropbox contents could be set to /somelocation/Dropbox while on box456, Dropbox contents for the same account could be set to /anotherlocation/Dropbox

My initial thought was a script that modifies config.db upon login, to change the 'dropbox_path' to whatever it needs to be for that machine.  But that would get nasty and cause all sorts of problems if the user is logged into more than one machine at a time.

Let me know if any clarification is needed.

Comment: Probably the best thing is if they had some sort of --config option for passing different config directories.  Something like 'dropbox --config=~/.dropbox/box123/'.  I don't think they have this though.  You can check the source and see if it could be added, but having looked at the dropbox.py CLI script, it looks like they probably hardcode a lot of that stuff so it may not be very simple.